# How do I delay javascript from running until inside the browser's view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, joomla3.0

I am looking to run a count up script that runs once it is within the browser view, like it does on the video player module for chicagolawyer.com. As far as I can tell, they accomplish this using jquery.appear.js ([Link](http://morr.github.io/appear.html)) and I have found a count up script ([link](https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/)) that I have been able to make work on the website I am designing, but have not been able to determine how to implement the browser view delay script. Here is the code I am inputing on my Joomla module:

```
<h1 id="casesWon"></h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
    useEasing : true,
    useGrouping : true,
    separator : ',',
    decimal : '.',
    prefix : '',
    suffix : '% Cases Won'
};
var count1 = new CountUp("casesWon", 0, 98, 0, 10, options);
$('casesWon').on('appear', count1.start());
</script>
```

This code works without delay if I switch the last line to just count1.start(); so I am just trying to figure out what I am doing wrong with jquery.appear.js. I am a novice when it comes to Javascript so I am sure it is something simple that I am missing. the documentation provided for the jquery script seems vague but is probably enough for people who understand jquery more than I do. Please help.

Comment: well, first off, you should pass an anonymous function in this case to do the work, otherwise you're going to lose reference to the instance. Additionally, `$('casesWon').on('appear', count1.start());` is basically equivalent to `count1.start()` unless `count1.start()` returns a function event handler.

Comment: Thank you for the observation, complete novice at this so I will have to figure out how to pass an anonymous function but I am sure I can get it. as far as what count1.start() does, it begins the count up. I modified the end to `$('#casesWon').on('appear', function() {
count1.start();
});`
but this resulted in no difference. Not sure if this is what you meant by anonymous function, again I am a complete novice at this.

Comment: If by `demo.start()` you mean `count1.start()` from your question, then yes that's what i was hinting at. did it work?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Edited my previous comment. Unfortunately no difference. Where I think I am getting it wrong is misunderstanding how jquery.appear.js works. [link](http://morr.github.io/appear.html) to the script example, don't know it will help in understanding but worth looking at.

Comment: I see what you mean. It's likely that the event isn't even being triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of reading and experimentation, I finally found out what to do to get these 2 scripts to work together. Rather than inputing straight code into a module, a 3rd script was created. The script is as follows:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $casesWon = $('#casesWon');

    var optionsCases = {
        useEasing : true,
        useGrouping : true,
        separator : ',',
        decimal : '.',
        prefix : '',
        suffix : '% Cases Won'
    };

    var countCases = new CountUp("casesWon", 0, 98, 0, 10, optionsCases);

    $('#casesWon').appear();

    $(document.body).on('appear', function(e, $affected) {
        // this code is executed for each appeared element

        console.log( $affected );
        $affected.each(function() {         
            countCases.start();
        });
    });

});
```

When I do this, the count up script waits until an element with the id "casesWon" is within the browser view and then starts the counting. Thanks to @monxas and @KevinB for attempting to help. The person who voted down this question can screw because I looked for an answer to this on stackoverflow before doing my own research on how other sites do this. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using

```
$('#casesWon').on('appear', count1.start());
```

instead of

```
$('casesWon').on('appear', count1.start());
```

Maybe just a typo here, maybe a typo on the code! ;)

Edit:
also, You probably need to use it like this:

```
$('#casesWon').on('appear', count1.start);
```

To prevent from executing at load

Comment: Thank you for the observations. I have tried with and without #, with and without () and sadly this has not changed the result.

Comment: One note about this answer: the last snippet is REALLY close, but it suffers from the problem of you're passing the function stored in `start`, and it will be executed with a context of the element the event is triggered on rather than the `count1` instance, which could (will in this case) cause further problems.